# Angular Formly - Highlight field based on custom validation

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

Currently, I have a formly field set up as such:

```
    {
      key: 'id',
      type: 'input',
      validators: {
        validId: function($viewValue, $modelValue, scope){
          var value = $modelValue || $viewValue;
          if(value){
            return isAlphanumeric(value);
          }else{
            return false;
          }
        }
      },
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'ID',
        options: [],
        required: true
      }
    },
```

isAlphanumeric() is a function I wrote that determines if a string is alphanumeric--this works as intended. However, the user is still allowed to Submit the form (which obviously does not work, as it will produce en error).

How might I go about highlighting the field red (as if it were a required field that was not filled in) if the contents are not valid, preventing the user from submitting until they enter a valid value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and assign css classes based off of an expresion. for example (taken straight from their page)

```
<p ng-class="{strike: deleted, bold: important, 'has-error': error}">Map Syntax Example</p>
```

implemented with your code

```
<p ng-class="{strike: validId(1,2,yourscope), bold: important, 'has-error': error}">Map Syntax Example</p>
```